# Convert unix timestamp between different timezones and different DST in Java

Tags: java, timezone, dst, java.util.date

**PROBLEM SOLVED** External device was computing and sending non-standard 2 hours shifted timestamp, which hugely confused me and started this thread. **TIMESTAMP BY ITSELF IS NOT AFFECTED BY TIMEZONES** , timezones apply only when converting in/from human readable forms.

---

I have timestamp (seconds from unix epoch) in UTC timezone - no DST (daylight saving time).

I want timestamp (seconds from unix epoch) in "Europe/Prague" timezone, that uses DST.

I used to think that unix timestamp is unbound by timezones, that timezones affect only process of converting timestamp to human readable formats. But it doesn't look like that. And the more I am trying to convert it (using Calendar and TimeZone classes), the more confused and lost I am getting.

this code DOES NOT work as expected:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(ts*1000);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Prague"));
return cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
```

Comment: What does it do? What happens when you printout the cal between each line of code?

Comment: You should perhaps state whether you'd be interested in [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) solutions, because I suspect you will start to receive them.

Comment: @Peter for recent timestamp '1366642620' it returned the same one - no converting happened. If I try to print out that timestamp in PHP in UTC and Europe/Prague timezones, I get different times: 14:57 and 16:57

Comment: When you getTimeInMillis() you are discarding the TimeZone you just added.  See my example in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a way to "convert" a timestamp, it is always the number of milliseconds from the epoch.

You can use a DateFormat to format the timestamp into a format with a time zone applied, or use a Calendar to look at the hours, minutes, and seconds with a time zone applied.

getTimeInMillis() gets the timestamp back just the same as you put it in, the number of milliseconds from the epoch:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code to convert epoch between timezones.

```
public static long convertTimeZone(long lngDate, String fromTimeZone,
        String toTimeZone) {        
    Calendar fromTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));
    fromTime.setTimeInMillis(lngDate);
    Calendar toTime = new GregorianCalendar(
            TimeZone.getTimeZone(toTimeZone));
    toTime.set(Calendar.DATE, fromTime.get(Calendar.DATE));
    toTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, fromTime.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    toTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, fromTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    toTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    toTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    toTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, fromTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    toTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, fromTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    LOG.debug("Converted " + fromTime.getTimeInMillis() + " to "
            + toTime.getTimeInMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");      
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));        
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");      
    sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(toTimeZone));
    LOG.debug("Converted " + sdf.format(fromTime.getTime()) + " to " + sdf1.format(toTime.getTime()));
    return toTime.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Output:

```
System.out.println(convertTimeZone(new Date().getTime(),"America/New_York","Asia/Singapore"));
Converted 1384514879944 to 1384468079944
Converted 15-Nov-2013 06:27:59.944 EST to 15-Nov-2013 06:27:59.944 SGT
```

Comment: i have been doing this for over 4 hours. and i finally got the correct result. It seems to be either a bug in the java or the line you added  which adding milliseconds to toTime object, which result in making difference nearly 3 hours from utc to local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves as I would expect

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    printCalendar(cal);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(ts * 1000);
    printCalendar(cal);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Prague"));
    printCalendar(cal);
}

public static void printCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

prints

```
2013/04/22 13:28:06.451 +0000
2013/04/22 13:28:06.000 +0000
2013/04/22 15:28:06.000 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert between two timezone like this:

**1.Suppose this is a date and time in the EST timezone**

```
String value = "2006-11-28 09:45:12";  
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

**2.Parses the value and assumes it represents a date and time in the EST timezone**

```
Date d = df1.parse(value);     
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
```

**3.Formats the date in the CET timezone**

```
System.out.println(df2.format(d));
```

Comment: I have seen similiar example, but it's input is in (hour,minute,second) format and not in unix timestamp. The point of my problem is that I don't know how to load 'unix timestamp' from different timezone. Calendar.setTimeinMilis() behaves as if it works in system timezone instead of timezone set in Calendar object.

Comment: How do yoy get an actual Date instead of a String?